# How do I transform this equotation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My first question here :)

So. I have

$$
\sqrt{x^2+x}
$$ and if I multiply this with $$ \frac{1}{x} $$ I will get $$ \sqrt{\frac{1}{x} + 1}  $$ but how?

wolframalpha suggesting this. but i dont know how I get there.

thanks

Comment: hm i think i found it by myself already.
writing 1/n as 1/sqrt(n^2)) and then i can put the radical above the whole fraction and then i can shorten the term

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: For what it is worth, there is no equation here. Lots of formulas, no equations.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $\,x>0\;$ (otherwise you can **not** do what you want):

$$\frac1x\sqrt{x^2+x}=\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+x}=\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}(x^2+x)}=$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac x{x^2}}=\sqrt{1+\frac1x}$$.

Remember that $\,\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\;$ , so  $\,x>0\implies x=\sqrt{x^2}\;$ ...

Comment: yes. and as long as I'm trying to look for an limit in a series, im in positive numbers. so thanks!:)

Comment: The beautiful thing is the quality is worth for values other than $x>0$, it's just this method that requires $x>0$.

Comment: @GitGud, I honestly doesn't understand what you meant to say...

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean the equality $\dfrac {1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+x}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac {1}{x}}$ is true for $x=-1$.

Comment: Ah, ok then. Yes, if the factor in the root vanishes then we're done, and if it does so when $\,\frac1x\;$ still is defined then better than better. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, it is possible to apply the above method when $\,x<0\;$ but multiplying by $\,-1\,$: $$\frac1x=-\frac1{-x}=-\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}}\ldots$$

Comment: I'm also confused by the values of x now. Is it now allowed to do that transformation while x < 1? or just with x = -1?